# Is it proper syntax to "nest" id declarations inside other id declarations in CSS?

Tags: css, nested

So, I'm not sure what I've stumbled upon here. I'm working with some CSS and I know it is common place to do something like this:

```
#content{
    /* Style the content div. */
}
#content p{
    /* Style all p elements in the content div. */
}
```

I'd like to give one specific p element a `float:right` style. Only one such p element will occur in the content element. Naturally, I'd just give this element an id, but then I had the idea to do it this way:

```
#content #right_floating_p{
    float:right;
}
```

This works when I run the code, but I was wondering about best practice and whether or not this actually does anything scope wise. I could just as easily define a separate id for right_floating_p, but to me it feels natural that it should be defined with the content id because it will be used only on one p element inside the content element.

If anyone has any information about this syntax, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's redundant since an id should be unique on a page. You can select on `#right_floating_p` directly. I'd use a class, though: it's more flexible.

Comment: I realize it does the same thing, but it seems strange that I'd even be able to define it like that. Also, I know there's a type of CSS (or something like it) that uses scope, so I was wondering if this was being compiled as that even though it's in a .css file.

Comment: It could be useful if you use the same stylesheet in different pages where you have the same element ids. Think that although the ids must be unique within the page, they don't have to be unique within the site (eg: if you assign an id to the body tag, you could display the nav with id #menu with different colors depending on the site section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to *only* include the last ID. This is fairly standard [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). What if you want to change the first ID `#content`, but the last one `#right_floating_p` still makes sense and shouldn't change? There is more room for error if you specify something unnecessarily.

Other reasons this is good:

- Smaller, faster (but barely) download size for your users.
- More readable, in my opinion.
- Faster (but barely) performance.

Over-qualifying tags [is bad practice](https://css-tricks.com/efficiently-rendering-css/) in general, as far as performance goes. Browsers read your selectors from right-to-left, by the time it interprets your `#content` selector, that information is pointless. My advice is to not trust that the browser will optimize for this.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. I suppose there really is no reason to define an id in an id since they are completely unique. Thanks for the links. I'm not great with CSS, so I didn't even know what to look for. \=)

Answer (score 1):

Alvaro nailed it in [his comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682495/is-it-proper-syntax-to-nest-id-declarations-inside-other-id-declarations-in-cs#comment47502557_29682495).

The `id` must be unique on the page, but not necessarily across the whole site. So, for instance, if you had the `#right_floating_p` element on every page, but it had a `#content` element as an ancestor only on a certain page where you wanted it styled differently, then you'd want to use the `#content #right_floating_p` selector to apply the context-specific style.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest only using the most precise selector as you can, not only for readability and file size, but also for specificity.

CSS selectors have a [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/) to them, so if you were to override it later (such as with a media query), the more specific selector will override the less specific one.

```
#content #right_floating_p {
    color: red;
}
div #right_floating_p {
    color: green; /* Will not apply, as it's less specific */
}
p {
    color: black; /* Even less specific */
}
```

It will work having the first selector, but it's not necessary.